# What is the simplest way to set the line height of a UIlabel using TextKit in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, textkit

I'm assuming I can do this concisely with `TextKit`.

- I don't need backwards compatibility.
- I don't want to destroy any existing attributes on any
  `NSAttributedString` instances involved.
- I don't necessarily mind subclassing `UILabel` if I can get a `setLineSpacing:` implementation that doesn't destroy any paragraph styles set up in my storyboard

Answer (score 2):

UILabel isn't built with TextKit on iOS7, at least not in a way that is accessible to developers. You'd need to use UITextView to get access to TextKit.

Take a look at TTTAttributedLabel to see if it does what you're wanting. If not, it likely could be modified to do it.